flutter_tts package not working on Android 14 with Tamil language
I am working on a Flutter project and using the flutter_tts package for text-to-speech functionality. My app includes Tamil words, and the TTS feature works fine on devices with Android versions below 14. However, it does not work on devices running Android 14.
Flutter 3.19.6
flutter_tss: 4.0.2
Android version: 14
Language: Tamil
I have followed all the steps in the flutter_tts package README. I have configured build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml as instructed.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I expected the TTS functionality to work on Android 14 devices as it does on earlier versions.
